# Jquery remove class on multi (duplicated) IDs

Tags: jquery, html

Hello I have 2 menu tabs in same page, but with diffent IDs and want to handle it with jQuery.

Right now i got it to show and hide the `<div>`, but I can't get it to remove the class from the correct `tablink`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.tablinks').click(function(){
        var tab_id = $(this).attr('show');
        var tabHide = $(this).attr('hide');

        $('#tab'+tabHide).removeClass('active');
        $("#date"+tabHide+", #seo"+tabHide+", #links"+tabHide+", #notat"+tabHide).hide();

        $(this).addClass('active');
        $("#"+tab_id).show();
    });

});
```

I have this listner to the menu tabs.

And then I got the 2 menus:

```
<button id="tab2" hide="2" show="date2" class="tablinks active">Dato</button>
<button id="tab2" hide="2" show="seo2" class="tablinks">SEO</button>
```

And

```
<button id="tab3" hide="3" show="date3" class="tablinks active">Dato</button>
<button id="tab3" hide="3" show="seo3" class="tablinks">SEO</button>
```

Can anyone guide me here?

My loop:

```
$x = mysqli_query($mysql_link, "SELECT * FROM dagenshug_imageslider");
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($x)) {

        $imageslider = $row;

        echo "
        <div style=\"width: 98%; border: 1px solid #dddedf; border-radius: 5px; min-height: 100px; margin-top: 15px; overflow: hidden; min-height: 335px;\">
            <div style=\"margin: 8px; border-bottom: 1px solid #dddedf;\"><img src=\"https://dagenshug.dk/NewBackOffice/gfx/icons/payment-icon.jpg\" style=\"padding-right: 5px;\">#".$imageslider['id']." - Unique click: ".$imageslider['clicks']."</div>
            <div style=\"clear: both; float: left; width: 20%; margin: 10px;\"><img src=\"https://dagenshug.dk/gfx/banner/".$imageslider['image_link']."\" style=\"width: 100%;\"></div>
            <div style=\"float: left; width: 75%; margin: 10px;\">
                <div class=\"tab\">
                    <button id=\"tab".$imageslider['id']."\" hide=\"".$imageslider['id']."\" show=\"date".$imageslider['id']."\" class=\"tablinks active\">Dato</button>
                    <button id=\"tab".$imageslider['id']."\" hide=\"".$imageslider['id']."\" show=\"seo".$imageslider['id']."\" class=\"tablinks\">SEO</button>
                    <button id=\"tab".$imageslider['id']."\" hide=\"".$imageslider['id']."\" show=\"links".$imageslider['id']."\" class=\"tablinks\">Links</button>
                    <button id=\"tab".$imageslider['id']."\" hide=\"".$imageslider['id']."\" show=\"notat".$imageslider['id']."\" class=\"tablinks\">Notat</button> 
                  </div>
                <div id=\"date".$imageslider['id']."\" class=\"tabcontent\" style=\"display: block\">
                    <b>Start dato</b><br>
                    <br>
                    <input type=\"date\" id=\"startdate\" class=\"input-imageslider\" value=\"".$imageslider['date_start']."\"><br>
                    <br>
                    <b>Slut dato</b><br>
                    <br>
                    <input type=\"date\" id=\"enddate\" class=\"input-imageslider\" value=\"".$imageslider['date_end']."\"><br>
                    <br>
                </div>
                <div id=\"seo".$imageslider['id']."\" class=\"tabcontent\" style=\"border: 0px;\">
                    <b>Alt tekst</b><br>
                    <br>
                    <textarea cols=\"80\" rows=\"11\" class=\"input-imageslider\">".$imageslider['alt_text']."</textarea>
                </div>
                <div id=\"links".$imageslider['id']."\" class=\"tabcontent\">
                    <b>Link til side</b><br>
                    <br>
                    <input type=\"date\" id=\"startdate\" class=\"input-imageslider\" value=\"".$imageslider['date_start']."\"><br>
                    <br>
                    <b>Slut dato</b><br>
                    <br>
                    <input type=\"date\" id=\"enddate\" class=\"input-imageslider\" value=\"".$imageslider['date_end']."\"><br>
                    <br>
                </div>
                <div id=\"notat".$imageslider['id']."\" class=\"tabcontent\">
                    <h3>Notat</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>";


    }
```

Comment: Looks like you're duplicating IDs, they're supposed to be unique

Comment: Yiir, i had that i my mind, so how can i get around this ?, if using $('.tablinks').remov..... then i will remove the class for id3 too ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is you have duplicated IDs.

The [jQuery id selector `$("#myId")`](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) will only bring one element, even it there are several with that ID.

So, for your case, the quickest solution is to replace the id selector with [the attribute equals selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/). In other words, change from:

```
$("#myDuplicatedId")
```

to

```
$("[id=myDuplicatedId]")
```

In your code, that means changing those middle lines to:

```
$('[id=tab'+tabHide+']').removeClass('active');
$("[id=date"+tabHide+"], [id=seo"+tabHide+"], [id=links"+tabHide+"], [id=notat"+tabHide+"]").hide();
```

Check a [**demo fiddle here**](https://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/1p3gebkL/).

---

That being said, **if possible, it would be better if you removed those** duplicated IDs - that's invalid HTML - and **use classes instead**.

Here's a [**demo fiddle** of how that (using classes instead of IDs) would work](https://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/0zfxtjh0/). Here's what I did:

- Removed the IDs from and added classes to the `<button>`s
- Changed the line 7 of the JS code.

  - You probably have to change line 8 as well...

Comment: $("[id=myDuplicatedId]") That one helped ;) now it's working.. I think this is a little "code shit", so what is the right way to do it ? @acdcjunior

Comment: @TheBoyHasAName Haha, it is a bit of "code shit", yes, I'd say too. The best way is to use classes (whenever you have duplication, actually).  I added a fiddle showing how you would do it (notice that I removed the IDs, added classes, and changed the line 7 of the JS code).